# Why printf() prints such a thing?

Tags: c

I found a problem at internet such that there is a **C** program which like-

```
int main(){
   int a = 123;
   printf("%d", printf("%d",a));
   return 0;
}
```

I run this program at **Codeblocks** and find result **1233**.
My question is that why printf() acts like this?

Comment: Curious: what did you expect to be the printout?

Comment: I did not expect anything. I just run the code at codeblocks and find out such an output. So I was curious, why? @chux

Answer (score 6):

see `printf` is a function which returns `int`. Where `int` is a number of `characters` printed.
 
**This is a `printf` prototype**

```
int printf(const char *restrict format, ...)
```

**As per your program:**

```
printf("%d", printf("%d",a));
```

`printf("%d",a)` where `a` is `123`, so it prints `123` and returns `3`
And `printf("%d", printf("%d",a));` becomes `printf("%d",3);` So it prints prints `3` alone
**So your output is:**
`1233`

Answer (score 3):

Break it up to understand it. The [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) function's Return Value
On success, is the total number of characters successfully written.

`printf("%d",a)` successfully writes 3 characters and then returns the value as a second parameter to be passed to the original call

```
printf("%d", 3 );
```

Second `printf` is passed as a parameter is evaluated and then its result is passed in the outer `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Printf always return the number of characters. And since a=123 implies 3 characters so output is coming as 1233. you will understand from this example.

```
int main(){
  int a = 123;
  int b=printf("%d",a);
  printf("\n%d", b);
  return 0;
}
```